.NET 8.0 Docker : OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
After I upgraded the project from microsoft .net Core 3.1 to .NET 8.0 I can no longer connect to an old external server via HttpClient call.
The error is:
OpenSslCryptographicException: error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure
The problem is only after I made the docker image and the software runs in the container.

SSL v3 is obsolete and insecure; also see the Wikipedia page on the POODLE attack.  Do you explicitly request this broken protocol version?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

sslv3 only refers to the fact that the error message exists since sslv3 version, not that you are using sslv3, because in .net8.0 it is not even supported. The example is in the Answer

Example: var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsesya");
await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

The solution comes from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/107172.
To apply the second solution to modify the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file I found this solution:
I extracted the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file of the .net8.0 version from the container, I modified the file by inserting these instructions:
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2

In the project I put the modified openssl.cnf file and in the dockerfile with the instruction:
COPY Docker/openssl_v8.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

I applied the file with the changes

sslv3 only refers to the fact that the error message exists since sslv3 version, not that you are using sslv3, because in .net8.0 it is not even supported.
